# UITableView accessory shown twice

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I use a UITableView with custom cells. Each cell has the accessory set to DisclosureIndicator.
When I am in portrait mode it's fine. When I rotate and go in landscape mode then the accessory is twice there: at the portrait position, and at the landscape position.
I also checked the cell subviews and when I am in landscape the UIButton for the accessory is twice.

Anybody else encountered this issue? Any idea to fix it?

---

So to sum it up this is what we have:

A UITableView that has a data source and uses some custom cells. These cells don't do much they only contain a UILabel which displays the document name.

In portrait mode we have:

```
Document 1           >

Document 2           >

Document 3           >
```

In lanscape mode we get:

```
Document 1           >           >

Document 2           >           >

Document 3           >           >
```

---

Our table source (please note that this is C#):

```
public class DocumentTableSource : MvxSimpleTableViewSource
{
    public DocumentTableSource(UITableView tableView) : base(tableView, typeof(DocumentTableCell), null)
    {
    }

    public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return DocumentTableCell.GetCellHeight();
    }
}
```

Our custom cell (please note that this is C#):

```
[Register("DocumentTableCell")]
public class DocumentTableCell : MvxTableViewCell
{
    public const int CELL_HEIGHT = 44;
    public static NSString Key = new NSString("DocumentTableCell");
    private bool initialized;
    private UILabel lblDoc;

    public DocumentTableCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
        lblDoc = new UILabel() {TextColor = AppearanceSettings.ColorDefault};
        this.DelayBind(() =>
        {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<DocumentTableCell, Document>();
            set.Bind(lblDoc).To(p => p.Name);
            set.Apply();
        });
    }

    public static float GetCellHeight()
    {
        return CELL_HEIGHT;
    }

    public override void UpdateConstraints()
    {
        base.UpdateConstraints();

        if (!initialized)
        {
            ContentView.AddSubview(lblDoc);
            ContentView.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

            ContentView.AddConstraints(
                lblDoc.AtBottomOf(ContentView, 6),
                lblDoc.AtLeftOf(ContentView, AppearanceSettings.HORIZONTAL_MARGIN)
            );
            initialized = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code. It will be a lot easier to help out.

Comment: Hi @matsr, in fact the code is written in C# with MonoTouch that's why I want to avoid posting it. I will get much more feedback if it's in the Objective C section. And in fact MonoTouch is just bindings on top of iOS native methods. I added more comments to my initial question, I hope it will help to find out what is going on.

Comment: I will also add the MonoTouch code as soon as possible.

Comment: Show us where `Accessory`is used in your base class (`MvxTableViewCell`), check out methods that are called on interface orientation change, such as `LayoutSubViews`.